# how to fix copy paste and undo error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

i am using Ubuntu 18.04 platform, from few days facing copy/paste error issue and ctrl key also not working(but ctrl +A works better). whenever i press ctrl+c or v it isn't working just i can see only letter "c" typed on screen i googled to fix the bug, tried all my ways ***such as reset the keyboard or setting keyboard as IBUS*** but have not got result.help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Test for hardware failure: Try your keyboard in a different system. Try a different keyboard in this system.

Comment: no issue in hardware, otherwise cltrl+A wouldnt have been work. any other way??